# Fill arbitrary areas with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting the decision surface of a complex classifier with `matplotlib`.  Currently, I am using a scatterplot with some hardcoded sizes and whatnot that "look" right.  The surface is not linear, or even connected.  It really needs to be plotted point by point.

```
g = np.mgrid[0:2:0.02, 0:10:0.1]
xx = np.vstack(map(np.ravel, g)).T

pred = clf.predict(xx)

plt.scatter(xx[:,0], xx[:,1], c=pred, s=4)

plt.show()
```

If my grid is too "coarse", the plot has spaces.  If my grid is too "fine", my classifier takes forever to perform the prediction.  If the `s` parameter of my scatterplot is too big, then the blobs cover each other up.  Is there a better way to fill in arbitrary areas with matplotlib?

*Note* this is not the classifier I'm using, but you can use this to test the above code:

```
clf = sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB()
x = np.array([[0.4,4],[0.6,7]])
y = np.array([0,1])
clf.fit(x,y)
```

For example:

[image]

There are "spaces" in the fill.  Currently, I am trial-and-error guessing the appropriate relationship between the grid `g`, the size `s`, and the figure size.  Is there a `matplotlib` function whereby I provide some points, and it does something smart to figure out the "spaces"?

Comment: Show a plot and explain what you don't like about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just plot the image, or use a filled [contour plot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html). If you have

```
X, Y = np.mgrid[0:2:0.02, 0:10:0.1]
```

and

```
Z = pred.reshape(X)
```

Just plot it as

```
contourf(X, Y, Z)
```

There are several ways in which you can control the interpolation. You can refer to the documentation. Make sure to check the examples at the end of the documentation for examples.